# Correctly position rotated text (with letter spacing / html5 / CSS)

Tags: css, html

I have read and tried most of the answers given about this topic on Stackoverflow, but none seem to work for me (rotating yes, position it correctly no). My problem:

- Rotate the text -90 degrees
- Position the -90 degrees text correctly as the picture below (End Result).
- Code should work for responsive design (%)

I added the complete code in JSFiddle (including my header above the content). I added the grey header to clarify that there is content above before the image/title/text begins: [**Link to JSFiddle code**](https://jsfiddle.net/md4zpxwn/)

How do you (1) rotate the text and more importantly (2) how do you position the rotated text similar to the end result:

[**See End Result image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IilTC.png)

**HTML code (see JSFiddle):**

```
<header>

<div class="header-wrap">

<div class="header-left"></div>
<div class="header-right"></div>

</div>

</header>

<section>

<div class="about-wrap">

<div class="about-img"><img src="http://www.sidneyblake.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Foggy-black-white-trees-alberta-landscape.jpg" ></div>
<div class="about-cnt">

<div class="about-ttl"><h1>ABOUT</h1></div>
<div class="about-txt"><p>Viris tibique scaevola mea ut, soluta forensibus suscipiantur et usu, his at munere fabellas. Cu harum quaestio cum, mei an quodsi evertitur adipiscing. Discere inermis dissentias ne mel. At eos possit elaboraret, sea ea vitae lobortis.

Id doming consulatu usu. Suas quot mei ut, ne habeo liberavisse his. Nec aeterno nostrud disputando ad, per in facete alienum. Cu his debitis inimicus facilisis.

In audiam tractatos per. Eu est zril reprehendunt. Probo appetere consetetur eam an. Augue ignota sit ex. Ex sanctus nominavi vix, nam ne mandamus intellegat. Vivendum principes eam no, qui ei pericula abhorreant. Mundi mediocrem scribentur duo ne, graeco theophrastus id his.</p></div>

</div> <!-- End of about-cnt -->


</div> <!-- End of about-wrap -->

</section>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the css rotate

```
.about-ttl {
width: 20%;
float: left;
transform: rotate(-90deg);
margin-top:100px; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/md4zpxwn/3/

Comment: Many thanks, its similar to the one Vandesh posted above. I see it has the same issue in which the ABOUT is running away (and not in a fixed position) when scaling down the screen. What I prefer is: the About text should be fixed inline with the text next to it (so the T outlines with the first line of text).

Comment: Thanks, this works as well, similar to the answer above plus it covers multiple browsers. I had some problems with Safari on the iPhone. I added the margin-right: -15px to counter the letter spacing. It sets the title nicely inline with text.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use [CSS3 transform property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) for rotating text.
2. Apply appropriate margin from top to position it.

```css
/* Header styles */

.header-wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.header-left {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}

.header-right {
  width: 50%;
  float: right;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

/* Paragraph styles */

h1 {
 font-size: 1em;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif; 
 letter-spacing: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.about-ttl h1{
margin-top : 80px;
transform: rotate(270deg);
-ms-transform : rotate(270deg); /* For IE9 */
-webkit-transform : rotate(270deg); /*Chrome, Opera and Safari*/
}

p {
 font-family: 'Maven Pro', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

/* Section styles */

.about-wrap {
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
}

.about-img {
 width: 50%;
 float: left; 
}

.about-cnt {
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
}

.about-ttl {
 width: 20%;
 float: left;
}

.about-txt {
 width: 60%;
 margin-right: 20%;
 float: right; 
}
```

```html
 <header>
   
    <div class="header-wrap">
    
    <div class="header-left"></div>
    <div class="header-right"></div>
    
    </div>
        
 </header>
  
  <section>
    
    <div class="about-wrap">
    
     <div class="about-img"><img src="http://www.sidneyblake.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Foggy-black-white-trees-alberta-landscape.jpg" ></div>
     <div class="about-cnt">
    
      <div class="about-ttl"><h1>ABOUT</h1></div>
            <div class="about-txt"><p>Viris tibique scaevola mea ut, soluta forensibus suscipiantur et usu, his at munere fabellas. Cu harum quaestio cum, mei an quodsi evertitur adipiscing. Discere inermis dissentias ne mel. At eos possit elaboraret, sea ea vitae lobortis.

Id doming consulatu usu. Suas quot mei ut, ne habeo liberavisse his. Nec aeterno nostrud disputando ad, per in facete alienum. Cu his debitis inimicus facilisis.

In audiam tractatos per. Eu est zril reprehendunt. Probo appetere consetetur eam an. Augue ignota sit ex. Ex sanctus nominavi vix, nam ne mandamus intellegat. Vivendum principes eam no, qui ei pericula abhorreant. Mundi mediocrem scribentur duo ne, graeco theophrastus id his.</p></div>
        
        </div> <!-- End of about-cnt -->
    
    
    </div> <!-- End of about-wrap -->
    
    </section>
```

Run the code snippet to see the result.

Comment: Many thanks for the help, the challenge I see is to keep the rotated text inline with the text next to it. So the T of About will always be in a horizontal line with the first line of the text, no matter how much you scale down the screen. Currently (when scaling the screen) the About text moves out of position.

Answer (score 1):

These changes to your CSS should get it pretty close to your [reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IilTC.png).

```css
.about-ttl {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-50%);
}

.about-ttl h1 {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  right: -15px;  /* Should match whatever the h1's letter-spacing length is. */
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/md4zpxwn/4/

In summary, rotate and translate the `.about-ttl` block so its edge is flush against the above `.header-wrap` element. Then position its child `<h1>` element so its edge is also flush (accounting for the `<h1>` element's `15px` letter-spacing). This styling should work for arbitrary lengths of text (besides "ABOUT"). If you do, and there are spaces in the text, be sure to add `white-space: nowrap;` to `.about-ttl`.

Comment: Many thanks, I think this method is closest to what I'm looking for and it works out well. When I scale down the screen the ABOUT remains in the same spot and inline with the text next to it.